# Mutating a column with unique conditions based around categorisation and quantiles

Tags: r, dplyr

```
set.seed(2)
example <- tibble(Score = round(rnorm(n = 12, 100, 20), digits = 0))

   Score
   <dbl>
 1    82
 2   104
 3   132
 4    77
 5    98
 6   103
 7   114
 8    95
 9   140
10    97
11   108
12   120
```

What I would like to do is to mutate a new variable `new`, which categories the smallest number as `alpha`, the second smallest number as `beta`, the third biggest number to the second quantile as `above median` and then the bottom two quantiles as `below median`.

I thought about doing multiple mutates to achieve this, but was wondering if anyone could offer a more elegant solution?

**Expected output**

```
   Score new         
   <dbl> <chr>       
 1    77 alpha       
 2    82 beta        
 3    95 above median
 4    97 above median
 5    98 above median
 6   103 above median
 7   104 below median
 8   108 below median
 9   114 below median
10   120 below median
11   132 below median
12   140 below median
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very naive implementation using dplyr's `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(2)
example <- tibble(Score = round(rnorm(n = 12, 100, 20), digits = 0))

#returns the second smallest number
second_min = function(x){
  t = which.min(x)
  temp_x = x[-t]
  m = min(temp_x)
  return(m)
}

example %>% mutate(category = case_when(Score == min(Score) ~ "alpha",
                                                       Score == second_min(Score) ~ "beta",
                                                       Score < median(Score) ~ "below_median",
                                                       Score >= median(Score) ~ "above_median"))
```

Note that all values equal to the minimum will be classified as "alpha" and all values equal to the second smallest value will be classified as beta

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic use case of `case_when` from `dplyr` where we can define multiple conditions and assign values to column accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  arrange(Score) %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ 'alpha', 
                         row_number() == 2  ~ 'beta', 
                         Score < median(Score) ~ 'below median', 
                         TRUE ~ 'above median'))



#    Score new         
#   <dbl> <chr>       
# 1   77. alpha       
# 2   82. beta        
# 3   95. below median
# 4   97. below median
# 5   98. below median
# 6  103. below median
# 7  104. above median
# 8  108. above median
# 9  114. above median
#10  120. above median
#11  132. above median
#12  140. above median
```